# CodeIgniter - Loading a view from another function in the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

Here's the issue :

If I call `www.mysite.com/quizz`, it loads my 'quizz' page.

But if I call `www.mysite.com/quizz/start` (containing the same code), the view is messed up because of broken links (images, css, ...)

Here is the content :

```
public function index()
{
       $this->load->helper('quizzsettings');
       $data['questions'] = getSettings();
       $this->load->view('head'); 
       $this->load->view('quizz', $data);
}
```

If I call another function (`www.mysite.com/quizz/start`), the layout fails :

```
public function start()
{
       $this->load->helper('quizzsettings');
       $data['questions'] = getSettings();
       $this->load->view('head'); 
       $this->load->view('quizz', $data);
}
```

As you know, CodeIgniter reads the URL like `www.mysite.com/class/method`, so it should be good, right?

Comment: _The views got messed up_? Then whats the url source for the images and css if they got messed. See the errors on Network Console.

Comment: Are you using relative paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to call your CSS, JS and images using an **absolute path**.  I suspect you are using a relative path.  If you haven't already it's best to create a common header view and use `base_url()`.  For example

```
<!-- Load CSS -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" />

<!-- Load JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/script.js"></script>
```

Obviously change the path to the files to be correct for your installation

Comment: I fixed it but as a new user I can't answer my question :/ Here it is : "Ok, got it.

I was using `base_url()` for my js but not for my css, I added it for the css and it was ok.

Then I added `base_url()` in my views for the images and it's fixed too.

Thanks for showing me the right way ! ;)"

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$this->function();` in your method but it is not advised. The broken code you are speaking of, from what I understand is the HTML which is loaded fine, but the images/css etc are broken because you are not calling the files properly.

Can you post a sample of HTML you get that is "broken" please? (from the browser, with view source or `ctrl+U' or`command+U` in 90% of the browsers)

I advise you to review your view's html and how you load images and css files, and you should be set.

lookup please codeigniter URL helper (it might be URI helper in the docs, don't recall) and they have a simple site_url() function that i advise you use... you can call it either by site_url('controller/method') or site_url('3rdparty/jQuery/jQuery.min.js') - nice hack that works great with both controller methods and files, and you don't have to care about where you install the software

Comment: I call my js/css this way, all is placed in head.php :

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/script.js"></script>`

in my view file, images are called this way : 

`<img src="./images/quizz/youtube.png">`

It works when I call my page the standard way (/quizz), but not if I call the function (/quizz/function).

I should use base_url() everywhere in my views ?

Comment: Probably not the solution because I call my css in head.php using base_url(), but here the link when I analyse the source : `http://localhost:8888/sanofi/**quizz/**css/style.css`. **quiz/** is added in the path, I don't know why, it works if I remove it...

Comment: As you point out above, yes, you should use base_url() to make absolute path to the resources. That way, it wouldn't matter from where you're calling it.

Comment: lookup please codeigniter URL helper (it might be URI helper in the docs, don't recall) and they have a simple site_url() function that i advise you use... you can call it either by site_url('controller/method') or site_url('3rdparty/jQuery/jQuery.min.js') - nice hack that works great